# Wicket AjaxLink generates no JavaScript

Tags: wicket

I started experimenting with Wicket AJAX functionality and wanted to implement an AjaxLink.

This is the associated markup/java-code:

```
<a wicket:id="testlink"></a>
---
AjaxLink<Component> link = new AjaxLink<Component>("testlink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("called");
    }
};
add(link);
```

But the `onClick`-method is never called, I guess because the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<a wicket:id="testlink" id="testlink7" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Robert for clarifying the ajax mechanisms of Wicket 6 - I'm rather new to this topic and the insights you gave me helped solve the problem.

Actually it was caused by some jQuery inconsistency I still haven't fully untangled, apparently coworkers used different jQuery-versions within different of our Wicket modules and somehow Wicket used not the one it was shipped with but a wrong one when trying to attach the event listener to the component.

When removing the unneccessary old jQuery libraries Wicket started to work fine - now I just have to get the components depending on the other jQuery libraries working again, but thats a different story :)

Answer (score 2):

This `href="javascript:;"` works because Wicket 6 uses JavaScript Event registration. Look at your webpage in some browser dev tool like in firefox. Point the inspector to the link and read it's id, then go the the head section and expand one of the `<script type= text/javascript></script>` tags. There you should find the id of the link and see that there is an line where a click event is attached to the id of the link. The URL there is executed when you click the link.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox Dev Tools]

Comment: Thanks, I see that and an according line is being generated. Still the method is not called, neither do I see the desired output nor is a Java-breakpoint triggered. Do you have any tips on that?

Comment: You have your link empty. Put in some text like: `<a wicket:id="testlink">Click here</a>` .Works for me.

Comment: Tried that, still not working. Besides even the empty link had a clickable area of something like 20x10 pixels due to the layout.

Comment: Additional remark: When I use the link of the click event (`Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./?0-2.IBehaviorListener.0-testlink","e":"click","c":"testlink7"});;`), the method/breakpoint is triggered. So it is not a problem of the ajax call itself but a problem that the call is not triggered from the webpage. I use no blockers whatsoever, every 'normal' javascript is working fine.

Comment: Try different browsers. Disable all addons . Try to use the builtin JS debugger in Firefox/Chrome. Add to the link an `IAjaxCallListener`: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/attributes/IAjaxCallListener.html and put JS `alert()`s in every handler and see which handlers get executed. Try it in an empty project generated freshly from the Maven Wicket Archteype. I dont have more ideas ...

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I removed the following onload on body tag and the AjaxLink onclick function worked again.

```
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('template-image/searchbto.png');">
```